# MySql: Join same table twice where a record doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `data`:

```
 +-------+-----------+------+-------+-------------+
 | id    | client_id | type | name  |    status   |
 +-------+-----------+------+-------+-------------+
 |   523 |   2       | one  | a     |   verified  |
 |   526 |   1       | one  | a     |   verified  |
 |   527 |   1       | one  | b     |   verified  |
 |   527 |   1       | two  | b     |   verified  |
 +-------+-----------+------+---------------+-----+
```

I need to get the `client_id`'s for those that `where type='one' and name='a' and status='verified''` AND DON'T have a record where  `type=one` and `name=b`

In my table above, the result would include `client_id = 2`.

How do I write a query like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a correlated suqbuery with a `NOT EXISTS` condition to filter out the unwanted records (ie those for which another record exists with the same `client_id`, with `type = 'one'` and `name = 'b'`)

```
SELECT *
FROM data d
WHERE 
    type = 'one' 
    AND name = 'a' 
    AND status = 'verified'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM data d1
        WHERE d1.client_id = d.client_id AND d1.type = 'one' and d1.name = 'b'
    )
```